# fpqc stackification

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, descent

I am reading Lurie's Tannakian paper (http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/Tannaka.pdf) and I am confused about one point.
At the end of page 3 he defines a stack-hom in any topos, which is defined by stackification. Now, I know that there are problems with sheafification in the fpqc topology. Assume the topos is fpqc sheaves on Spec Z, shouldn't there be a problem with stackifying things?

Has this stackification nothing to do with fpqc sheafification?

Is it that this particular stackificaion does not cause any problems?

I would be glad if someone could clear this all up for me.

Comment: Do you mean size problems? Stackification works for arbitrary *small* sites (see SGA or Vistoli's notes on descent theory).

Comment: right, Martin, that's what I was recalling. So, should I assume the topos is already sheaves on a small site so that these problems never arise? (I assume the fpqc site not to be small, right?)

Comment: In the first place, if the site is not (essentially) small, then you do not have a topos. (This is the "topological generator" axiom.)

Comment: @ZhenLin - not necessarily (at least in the 1-topos case). Weren't you at my talk at the CT meeting in Sydney? Or do you mean a _locally small_ topos?

Comment: Agh. I meant "Grothendieck topos".

Comment: wait, so sheaves on the fpqc site do not form a topos?

Comment: @John: No, unless you go to a higher universe, see the answer I just posted.

Comment: @ZhenLin: That's not quite right. You are misquoting the topological generator axiom. The site need not be essentially small, it just has to have a set of generators. E.g., take your site to be ALL manifolds, I mean, even allow non-2nd countable non-Hasudorff guys. This is not essentially small, but sheaves  on this do form a topos, since it's equivalent to just using $\mathbb{R}^n$s.

Comment: I meant essentially small site in the sense of Johnstone, which amounts to the same thing as the topological generator axiom. Of course, the fpqc site is not essentially small even in this sense.

Comment: @John: I deleted my answer because it contained a non-fixable error (I got confused between fpqc and fppf).However, I owe you the following:

Comment: If you take your site to be all affine schemes with the fpqc topology, then sheaves on this will not form a topos since this category is not small, and moreoever, you can't find a set of affines from which you can cover every other (i.e. it is not topologically generated).

Comment: @John: I don't see in Lurie's paper where he mentions which Grothendieck topology he is using. Is it possible he is really using the etale topology? (Since algebraic stacks are stacks for that topology as well?)

Comment: I never said he was using the fpqc topology. He makes a definition which works in any topos, and I was confused as I thought fpqc sheaves formed one. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summing up the comments: stackification works in any topos; fpqc sheaves do not form a topos (size does matter).

Comment: You can take a larger universe of sets, so that your site becomes small in that universe, and *large* sheaves (sheaves with values in sets in that larger universe) *will* form a topos. The problem is that, sheafification (and more generally stackification) of a small presheaf, might yield a large one.